# Bundling entire module including its components in Angular 4

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular4-router

For production release, i want each module as a separate bundle because if any changes happened in future ill just replace that particular module alone. Currently, im bundling modules via lazyloading in angular 4 but in that bundle,  components code are not available it was in main.bundle.js. How to do?
Sample structure below,

> -app
>   --module1
>   ---component1.ts
>   ---component1.css
>   --module2
>   ---component2.ts
>   ---component2.css
>   --app.component.ts
>   --app.component.html

Comment: Can you share your app.module and one of separate component module?

Comment: I found the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is to be able to change a module in the future without touching the other modules, then it doesn't depend on what feature you're using, but on how you construct your application.

Now, if you want to use lazy loading, you have to keep in mind that Angular doesn't load the lazy loaded modules at start (that's the principle of lazy loading). This means that, as you have seen, they will be in separate files that will be called and loaded on demand.

By the way, why would you see your `main.bundle.js` file ?

Comment: My question is, angular-cli bundles the file as per module wise. But in that bundle only configuration part is present not all the components code related to that module. I want entire module related code in a separate file.

Comment: When you bundle, you will see a message containing this : `chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 930 kB [initial] [rendered]`. This means your application is bundled into several bundles, each one having a particular content. If you use lazy loading, you will see a bundle for every module. If it isn't the case, you're not using lazy-loading correctly.

Comment: In output, `chunk {svp.module} svp.module.chunk.js () 4.87 kB  [rendered]` file has created. But in that file contains only module related configuration. I declared all components inside the declaration of that module.

Comment: If only the content bothers you, don't mind it. The content is bundled, minified, uglified, and only a fool would look inside to see how it works. But if you are a fool, sorry, I can't help you, I'm not one :D

Comment: hahaha.. then what is the use of bundling. Only fool can accept all without knowing anything. If you are fool then i dont need any suggestion from you.

Comment: @trichetriche you can add preloadingstrategy to load lazy loaded modules at start. `{preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules}`

Comment: The use of bundling is to give related content on a single file request. **[Angular has a guide on that](https://angular.io/guide/webpack)**. And you can use the `canLoad` guard to **[prevent modules from being loaded](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules)** if you want !

Answer (score 0):

you can add individual modules like

> module1/module1.module.ts

Inside this module declare the components you have used and import all other dependent modules

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Module1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule // Required for common directives
  ]
})
export class Module1Module {}
```

Now this module can be imported to your AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    Module1Module
  ]
```

Inside your routes, you can add lazy loading by

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'module1', loadChildren: './module1/module1.module#Module1Module'},
];
```

You can also add preloadingStrategy in your route defination to download all the lazy loaded modules initally to avoid downloading it when you visit that module route.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
  ]
})
```